# How to crop an image into a circle button in xml Android studio?

Tags: android, xml, button, android-studio

hey guys so I'm trying to make this circle button. And in that circle I want to put an image, like a person's profile picture. So if someone uploads an image, I need to be able to adjust the size and crop it and put it into a circle. Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish. And behind the circle is a red circle, just for aesthetics. Hope you guys can give me some insight or direction.  [image]

Comment: There are tons of libraries and solutions online, but I ended up making a circle mask image in photoshop or something and place it on top of my picture, with an alpha of a circle of course

Comment: But if your app has a lot of users you can't do that. There needs to be a way where if someone uses your app and selects and image, the program should automatically do the cropping and profile picture setting.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and just use Picasso or Glide, it's what everybody does for this type of thing....  See here for adding a border using Picasso: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236158/adding-borders-for-image-rounded-image-android

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily by using ImageView two properties:  background and src

1. Get a square image with transparent circle
2. Set step 1 image to the src property of an ImageView
3. Set the background of your ImageView with your avatar photo (square).

Please see here for the static avatar image solution: 
[ImageView in circular through xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22105775/imageview-in-circular-through-xml)

If your avatar is dynamic, then you need to set the background image dynamically and this post will help:

[Changing image view background dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7871767/changing-image-view-background-dynamically)

If you are using Picaso then use this: 
[android: create circular image with picasso](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26112150/android-create-circular-image-with-picasso)

However it has great performance concerns.

Comment: what do you mean by step 1?

Comment: @TheQ it means this : https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/18/Circle_frame.svg